# SCP behaving abruptly when adding VPC resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-organizations

I am using SCP policy to stop ec2 resource ( subnet, security group, instance, vpc) creation when they don't have tags. i am using tag policy to check for compliant tags.

But as soon as i am adding action and resource for vpc in my scp policy, i am not able to create subnet, security group.

Below SCP policy is working fine without vpc resource -

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1ForProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
        "ec2:CreateSubnet"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*"
      ],
     "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/project": [
            "true"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This SCP policy is breaking - i.e i am not able to create security group/subnet with proper tags aslo.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1ForProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
        "ec2:CreateSubnet",
        "ec2:CreateVpc"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*"
      ],
     "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/project": [
            "true"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone shed a light on this?

Comment: Shouldn't the effect of the second SCP be `Allow` ?

Comment: no @paolo. Condition will be evaluated and if the condition is not satisfied then Deny effect will take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommendable to combine different Actions and Resource in the same statement. It could cause unexpected behaviours or some issues. Also [not all actions are applicable to all resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html), you need to specify the suitable one.

So first it is necessary to split the statement into multiple ones. Then change the effect from Allow to Deny and condition to 'StringNotEquals'.

The SCP should be similar to this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1ForProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "project"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Statement2ForProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "project"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Statement3ForProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSubnet"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "project"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Statement4ForProjectTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateVpc"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "project"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. it is working great. 
But from this approach i think i will soon run into issue. I have 5 different type of tags (project, environment, partner,role,mangedby) and 11 ec2:resource types. If i follow this approach then i have to write a very long policy i guess which would be inappropriate. Would you suggest how to manage multiple tag keys.